# Which does 'only' intensify in: he only knew he was now married?

Tags: vocabulary

> He **only** knew he was now married.  (COCA)

In the sentence alone, when there aren’t any other sayings, can you tell which ‘*only*’ intensify: (1) previous noun, ‘*he*,’ as in '*The bar is for **members only***([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/only_2))'; (2) its following words, ‘*knew he was now married*.’ Or do you have to defer your decision until you get further contextual information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, it could mean

> 1. He alone (and nobody else) knew he was now married.
> 2. He merely knew (but did not fully comprehend) he was now married.
> 3. All he knew was that he was now married (he knew nothing more).

Practically, however, *he only knew* will usually mean 3, although in the strictest formal discourse *only* precedes the term it modifies and therefore 2 'should' be the default: most people would find other ways to express either 1 or 2.

And in speech there would be no ambiguity: the three meanings call for entirely different stresses and vowel lengths (**bold** is primary stress, *italic* is secondary):

> 1. **He on**ly · *knew* he was now *married*.
> 2. He only **knew** · he was *now* *mar*ried.
> 3. He *on*ly *knew* he was *now* *mar*ried.

So Yes, you need context; but of course the context is just as likely to be present in what precedes the statement as in what follows it.